# Preload images during scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery to alter the source of an image as the page scrolls. However, currently they are loading as they are displayed and i would like to have them preload several images prior to being shown.

HTML

```
<img src="/img/1.jpg" />
```

JQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
// Array of images to swap between
var images = [/img/1.jpg, /img/2.jpg, /img/3.jpg, /img/4.jpg];

var totalImages = images.length; 

var documentHeight = $(document).height();

// Work out how often we should change image (i.e. how far we scroll between changes)
var scrollInterval = Math.floor(documentHeight / totalImages);

$(document).scroll(function () {
// Which one should we show at this scroll point?
i = Math.floor($(this).scrollTop() / scrollInterval);
// Show the corresponding image from the array
$('img').attr('src', images[i]);
});
});//]]>
```

css

```
img {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
}
body {
height: 5000px;
}
```

Attempt.
I would like to add something similar to this to,

```
$(document).scroll(function () {    
    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
            (new Image()).src = this;
        });
    }

    i = Math.floor([i]+'1');

    preload([[i]]);
}
```

But cannot figure how to code it... (New to JS)

Comment: you need to quote strings in JavaScript.  `images = ['/img/1.jpg', '/img/2.jpg',` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop.

```
var nextTenImages = images.slice(i, i+10);    
// preload the next image
preload(nextTenImages);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/ygkWH/8/

**EDIT:** Credit to the following SO topic for preloading images: [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)